# How to get Intellij to launch browser automatically after spring-boot webapp is ready

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I just switched a Spring Boot webapp from an external war deploy in Tomcat to a direct jar deploy with Spring Boot (and its internal Tomcat).

For Tomcat Run/Debug Configurations, Intellij gives you the to open browser after launch and go to http://localhost:8080/.

How can I do something similar with a a Spring Boot RUn/Debug Configuration.  It runs the main class and just waits until I go to localhost:8080 from the browser myself.

Answer (score 15):

edit your run/debug configurations
in the bottom - click on '+' right above 'Build'
select 'launch web browser', put your app url, for example http://localhost:8181
 [image]

so you will have [image]

click apply/ok, with that when you click Run/play button, it will launch browser with your url after the build

Comment: Unfortunately, this launches the browser right away, it doesn't wait for the server to be started.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there is a way to do this. You can only launch external commands before launch it seems. Alternatively, you could try something like this in code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27378560/3166303).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is by making a Tomcat Server run configuration.

Comment: And how would you do that?