# Run spring boot from shell script and print URL on the console

Tags: shell, maven, spring-boot

I have shell script which is simply building and deploying my spring boot app.

Within this script I have only 1 command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Is it possible to print URL under which my app was deployed after deployment is successfully finished? 
The best would be if I can obtain this URL somehow and print it on the console.

EDIT
I used following solution

```
@Component
public class ListenerContainer {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ListenerContainer.class);

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void postStartupPrint() throws UnknownHostException {
        logger.info("Application deployed under: http://"
                + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
                + ":"
                + environment.getProperty("local.server.port"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try "[Launch browser automatically after spring-boot webapp is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27378292/launch-browser-automatically-after-spring-boot-webapp-is-ready)", pass your hostname depending on environment & some endpoint you wish.

Comment: I don't want to launch browser. I need this url on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log the url after your context is ready, which can be seen during `mvn spring-boot:run`

```
@Component
public class ListenerContainer {

    // autowire & get logic for hostname & context path

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void postStartupPrint() {
        System.out.println(hostname + contextPath + "/actuator/health");
    }
}
```

where `hostname` can be gathered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38919192/3641067), and `contextPath` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34089279/3641067)

This is just an idea, I have no environment to test, hope it would help!

[More on Spring Events](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events)