# Running a Spring Boot JAR Application does not open a URL(https://localhost:8080/) with a browser

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot JAR Application. When I run it, no browsers automatically show `https://localhost:8080/`. But typing manually the mentioned URL works fine, and the application runs.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class StockMaintenanceSystemApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(StockMaintenanceSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Do I need to set the `URL(https://localhost:8080/)` anywhere? If not, please correct my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "URL is not opening automatically" ?

Comment: i mean URL = "http://localhost:8080/"

Comment: I really have trouble understanding your problem. What to you mean with "opening automatically" and  "is typing manually" - where do you type it manually, into your browser bar? Then this is not really an issue at all.

Comment: Do you mean opening it should open your browser and load the url? automatic ?

Comment: you can refer this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50214877/7820277

Answer (score 2):

When you build the jar file and run it, it will not automatically open the browser for you.
The file jar is used when deploying on the server environment, this is completely different from the developer environment you're still used to, where when you use the IDE, your job is to just click the "run button", the IDE will build the jar file, run it and automatically open the browser for you.

The solution for you here is  you can write function that execute shell command like [that](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/) and call it on `main` function. The shell command can be `chrome.exe localhost:8080`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you mean that the browser doesn't open a new tab when you start a spring boot application.

If that is the case, it shouldn't open a new tab, it simply starts a service on your pc, you need to navigate to the address manually. It is simply not something that spring boot does.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a browser after running your application is `IDE`'s responsibility. IDEs can only open a browser when you package the application as a `WAR` file, configure an application server, like `Tomcat`, and restart the container via IDE.

So if you package the application as `JAR` file, it is necessary to open a web browser and type the desired link(`localhost:8080`). But there are some [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60449216/3881354) to cope with this situation.

Answer (score -2):

I resolved my problem.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class StockMaintenanceSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(StockMaintenanceSystemApplication.class, args);
        openHomePage();
    }

    private static void openHomePage() throws IOException {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/";
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
    }
}
```